# Flutter - How to print a receipt to bluetooth printer?

Tags: flutter

i m new to Flutter, and basicly i m still learning. I need to create a "print" receipt through a bluetooth printer module. The case is about shop app, i select some items, and it sums the total price. In the end i submitted, and it prints the receipt through bluetooth printer. I ve tried to search some plugin like pauldemarco's flutter_blue, but i still didnt get it how to do the print thing. I m using flutter, and i pull the data from MySQL.

My question is, "How to print a receipt display using bluetooth printer"?

Can anyone provide me some simple explanation, and if i can kindly ask a simple example code for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: did you find out the answer？ I have the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth API is a platform-specific API, so you should use [Platform Channel](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) in Flutter to deal with those APIs in the separate platform (Android and iOS). In a word, Platform Channel supports you communicate between Dart module and native module (android and ios)

From Dart module, user triggers an action of printing something, Dart module will send a message to the native module to request printing action, native module calls some specific APIs of OS to do it and when it's done, the native module sends back the result to Dart module to show the result to user.

Comment: any specific examples please ? I think Flutter is not going to be stable and famous because there's no any good support. No ?

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print

Answer (score 2):

You should try flutter-blue.dart for bluetooth receipt printer

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add some sample info to expand on how to use what is linked here.

Comment: You can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer). **NOTE**: Only works on android

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print